# get entire table td data using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have this weird requirement. I have a table and inside that table I have a form. I am handling that form with the help of Jquery. Is there any way that I can get the data of the `<td></td>` without having any id or class for that `<td>`.

My requirement is weird. I got this code from somewhere and now I need to manage this code. If this thing dont work, I will have to manually change the code line by line and there are hundreds of such forms.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>The data that i need </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> <form> My form </form> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, you can always loop through each `td` one by one and see if it contains a form....but I'd first concentrate on fixing the horrible, horrible design.

Comment: `$('table td:first').html()`?

Comment: So you want the form data? Or the content from the first td?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
html= $('table td:first').html();
```

And you can use it like this:

```
 alert(html);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bYccS/

Answer (score 0):

```
$($('table > tr > td')[0])
```

using this you will have the first td on the first tr

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery.each('td', function() {
      var text = $(this).html();    
 });
```